# UIBarButtonItem not change image automatically when switching dark mode/light mode

Tags: ios13, ios-darkmode

I am trying to integrate dark mode support to my app. But when setting image icon for UIBarButtonItem, it seem only works when the first time UIBarButtonItem is shown, it is not changed when I switch between dark mode/light mode.

When using that image with other UIButton, it works fine.
So I wonder if I am missing something?

P/s: I have to use that trick for updating image:

```
    let item: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()  
    let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 26, height: 19))  
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburger"), for: .normal)  
    button.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)  
    item.customView = button
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in iOS, but one way around this is, to use `traitCollection` delegate method to set the correct image manually.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    
    let imageAsset = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")?.imageAsset
    let resolvedImage = imageAsset?.image(with: traitCollection)
    
    self.YOUR_BUTTON.image = resolvedImage
}
```